# babel cli の使い方

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

ES6 でかかれたJSをIEとか古いブラウザでも動くようにしたいです

---

babel というのがあるみたいで早速インストールしてみたんですが

```
npm install -g babel
babel test.js
You have mistakenly installed the `babel` package, which is a no-op in Babel 6.
Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the `babel` package to the `babel-cli` package.

    npm uninstall babel
    npm install --save-dev babel-cli

See http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ for setup instructions.
```

となってしまったのでそこの指示にある通り

```
npm uninstall babel
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

でインストールしてコマンドたたいてみたんですが以下のようなエラーになります
どうやってインストールすればいいのでしょうか

```
babel test.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\chico\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\babel-cli\bin\babel.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
```

環境は
Windows10 PowerShell 上
npm -v
6.14.5

よろしくおねがいします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

babel-cli も古いためエラーになっています。`@babel/cli` を使ってください。

babel では v7.0.0-beta.3 から beta.4 に上げる際に、`@babel/` への移行を行っています: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v700-beta3-2017-10-15。詳しくはこちら: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#scoped-packages

まずは手元の環境にある古いライブラリたちを `npm uninstall babel-cli` などですべてアンインストールし、そのあと最新ドキュメントのインストール方法にしたがってください: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli